# Phonegap issue on adding platform

Tags: ios, cordova

I am new to Phonegap.
I have installed phonegap on my mac. I have installed latest xcode also.
I am following instruction from 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide.

I run successfully

```
 $ cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"
 $ cd hello
```

But after i run `cordova platform add ios` it gives following error.

```
    Krishnak:my-app krishnak$ cordova platform add ios
    Creating ios project...
    Unknown option: n
    Usage: head [-options] <url>...
        -m <method>   use method for the request (default is 'HEAD')
        -f            make request even if head believes method is illegal
        -b <base>     Use the specified URL as base
        -t <timeout>  Set timeout value
        -i <time>     Set the If-Modified-Since header on the request
        -c <conttype> use this content-type for POST, PUT, CHECKIN
        -a            Use text mode for content I/O
        -p <proxyurl> use this as a proxy
        -P            don't load proxy settings from environment
        -H <header>   send this HTTP header (you can specify several)

        -u            Display method and URL before any response
        -U            Display request headers (implies -u)
        -s            Display response status code
        -S            Display response status chain
        -e            Display response headers
        -d            Do not display content
        -o <format>   Process HTML content in various ways

        -v            Show program version
        -h            Print this message

        -x            Extra debugging output
    Cordova can only run in Xcode version 4.6 or greater.

Error: /Users/krishnak/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
Krishnak:my-app krishnak$
```

I have already installed `xampp` server on my computer. I m not sure if xampp is the problem.
Please suggest me how can i fix this problem.

Comment: my xcode version is Version 5.0.1 (5A2053)

Comment: if you don't mind, i suggest try to install 'MAMP' instead. it is more Mac-friendly rather than xampp

Comment: @Krishna Karki have you found solution for the issue

Comment: yes @Athimannil, there was the problem with xampp.

Comment: @KrishnaKarki What consequence has comment this line? Can you help me here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617471/cordova-platform-add-ios-in-mac-osx-yosemite I have the same error than you! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue may with xampp. It may due to the path environment, consider to edit your *.profile* and put the xampp binary path.

Or try to comment bin like  *# export /PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/bin:$PATH –*

hope this may help you.

Comment: Sorry I m new to mac. Where is .profile file located on mac? how to edit it?

Comment: open Terminal goes to xampp folder, put command "ls -a" 
you can see all files and put command "sudo vim filename" to edit it

Comment: Or jst uninstall xampp and try to create a new project again :)

Comment: `Krishnak:xampp krishnak$ ls -a
.  bin  htdocs  manager-osx.app
..  cgi-bin  htdocs alias uninstall.app
.DS_Store etc  logs  xamppfiles` 
here is no .profile file

Comment: @manukv can you give more details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617471/cordova-platform-add-ios-in-mac-osx-yosemite Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just execute the following command so that the head binary in `/usr/bin/` gets preference over the script installed by XAMMP:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your iOS SDK in your xcode 5. **Xcode** > **Preferences**

[image]

Comment: which one needs to install from the list ?