# Unable to compile phonegap for iOS

Tags: xcode, cordova, phonegap-build

unable to compiling ios in phonegap :( All the applications nodejs, phonegap, cordova, xcode are up to date. Still not able to compile the project.

here is the tutorial trying to follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qx3CgmKVM4E

[image]

xcode version os up to date (see the screenshot) 
[image]

Comment: The "Cordova can only run in Xcode version 4.6 or greater" - is that just a notice or telling you your version is too old?

Comment: @scunliffe Xcode is up to date version, see the screenshot

Comment: Check this out. The poster seems to have your same issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708592/phonegap-issue-on-adding-platform

Comment: @Marco Magrini The issue seems to be similar, I have already done those solutions unfortunately still not working :(

Comment: Try this command and see the output
`xcode-select -print-path`